# Understanding the position of .OBJ 3D objects

Tags: 3d, three.js, .obj

I'm trying to make a simple [THREE.js](https://threejs.org/)-powered visualization of what various objects look like in scale to the Empire State Building. So I bought [this very reasonably priced model for $2](https://www.cgtrader.com/3d-models/exterior/skyscraper/empire-state-building-ae9b61e19362f3a7396614fb203d7952), which comes in several formats including `.obj`. I then used THREE's [OBJLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/loaders/OBJLoader) to add it to the scene.

```
    container = document.getElementById("city");
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, 1, 1, 2000 );
    camera.position.set( 100, 0, -100 );

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x87CEEB );

    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xcccccc, 0.4 );
    scene.add( ambientLight );

    // load the ESB model
    var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

    loader.load(
        'data/esb.obj',
        function ( object ) { // called when resource is loaded
            ESB = object;
            scene.add( object );
        },
        function ( xhr ) { // called when loading is in progresses
            console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );
        },
        function ( error ) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    );
```

This successfully loads the OBJ file -- [demo here](http://mechanicalscribe.com/demos/esb/embed.html). (I would put on CodePen but don't have rights to redistribute the OBJ. Please don't steal it!)

As you can see, however, while I added some Axis Helpers that are vaguely visible in the distance, the ESB floats in on its side from the left:

[image]

Clearly I don't understand the .obj specification that well, though I've tried to read up on it. My questions are:

- Do OBJ files have absolute coordinates, such that, for some reason, the ESB would be way off from the center of <0,0,0>?
- Why is it moving? Can OBJ files have momentum, or is this an artifact of something I'm doing in Three.js?

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the model of the ESB is not centered at the origin. You can easily verify this if you import it into Blender. Try to reposition the loaded `OBJ` to the center of the scene via:

```
var boundingBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( object );
boundingBox.getCenter( object.position ).negate();
```

The movement of the object is not related to the `OBJ` format. I guess some application level code causes this behavior.